# About Aggregage/Sum column in SSAS Cube

Tags: ssas, cube, calculation

I am working on a simple project using SSAS Cube on SQL Server 2016 and SSDT2015. DW_Orders database is from Orders DW. The table factor orders contains attributes UnitPrice, Quantity and Discount with the calculation member TotalSale defined as [Measures].[Unit Price]*[Measures].[Quantity]*(1-[Measures].[Discount]), well as the FK members CustomerID and OrgID. I want to get the TotalSale based on Country-City Hierarchy from dimension dimCustomers. But I got the following result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Adbfp.png)

it is obvious that the UnitPrice, Quantity and Discount have been summed under the city or country  so that we got wrong and negative result of TotalSale from the calculation. Tried in the Edit Measure, cannot get what I expect. Need your help on some settings, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the aggregation type for the 2 measures(discount and unit price). By default, the type is SUM, you need to use Average. To do that, go to the measure group, select the measure and access its properties to set the aggregation.